# JavaScript Regular Expression. I try to catch floating point sililar expression and avoid some

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point

I am writing parser and I need to catch "numbers" but avoid chars such as [-+] before "e".
**My problem is that pattern marks "-" or "+" right after my mantissa but it should not.**

I use this pattern:
**/^[.0-9]+[-+e.0-9]*$/g**

```
//Test strings:
//wrong string - match - PROBLEM, but should not be because of '-' or '+' after mantissa
1.2-
2.3-e
1.2+
1.2+e
//wrong string - does not match - OK
-123
1.2b+3
+123
-123-e9
//right string - match - OK
1
1.
1.2
123.5
.2
1.2.
.2.
1e3
.e3
1.e3
1.2e3
1.2e+3
1.2e-3
1.2e3.
1.2e3.4
1.2e-399
1.2e+e3
```

String marked as 'wrong' should NOT be catch.
These strings will be split into table like this but in another module.
I just want to avoid them to be catch by my patern.
1.2-   // ['1.2','-']
2.3-e  // ['2.3','-','e']
1.2+   // ['1.2','+']
1.2+e  // ['1.2','+','e']

Do you have idea how to improve my pattern or it should be write differently?
[**TEST**](http://regexr.com/38ofe) `^[.0-9]+[-+e.0-9]*$`
[**SOLVED**](http://regexr.com/38ofn) `^\.?\d*(\.(\d+)?)?((?:e[+-]?|[+-]e)*\d+(\.\d+)?)?\.?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tweaked a little bit a solution I did for the regex101 quiz and I came up with this solution: [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vY8bC8)

`^[.,]?(\d)*([.,](\d+)?)?((?:e[+-]?|[+-]e)*\d+(\.\d+)?)?\.?$`

EDIT: A secon approach since the explanation of the question wasn't clear.

Final answer edited and accepted: `^\.?\d*(\.(\d+)?)?((?:e[+-]?|[+-]e)*\d+(\.\d+)?)?\.?$`

Comment: Almost done but `//good - not marked` should NOT match such as `-123 +123 -123-e9 1.2b+3`. They are wrong because 1st, 2nd, 3rd starts from `-` or `+`, last one contains `b`-wrong.

Comment: Another question: is like I did but without those `//good - not marked` marked as wrong?

Comment: Edited and now those aren't matching.

Comment: That is good and complicated ;) But it works, thank you! Give me a second to check Paul S. answers. I re-edited you answer to: `^\.?\d*(\.(\d+)?)?((?:e[+-]?|[+-]e)*\d+(\.\d+)?)?\.?$` becasue `,` are wrong in my application. Any way GOOD JOB.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it matches more, but not everything because I wasn't entirely sure about your "rules" (e.g. when are multiple `.` okay? why is `1b+1` okay? why is `e+e` or `1-e` okay?)

```
/^[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d+)(?:e[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d+))?$/g
```

[image: Graphic by debuggex.com]

[**DEMO**](http://regexr.com/38ofe)

Comment: Multiple `.` or `e` are okay because I will test match string later in other module which return `error` flag or not. `e+e` or `1-e` or `1+e` is okay. I know it does not search for exact float but I want to gently deal with such a mistakes. How did you draw that graph, where?

Comment: I just need to avoid match for strings such as `1.2- 2.3-e 1.2+ 1.2+e` which contains `[-+]` after mantissa (ex. `1.2`)

Comment: Anything matched by this _RegExp_ will be a legal _Number_ literal in _JavaScript_ (which is why I haven't edited it to conform with your `e+e` type thing). It will match `+x`, `-x` or just `x`, where `x` is one of e.g. `.1`, `1.`, `1` and then optionally matches a suffix beginning `e` followed by `+y`, `-y` or just `y` (`y` rules same as `x`)